# Display message in release mode for C++ metro app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I am using `OutputDebugString` to print out message in output window during C++ metro app debug mode. It works fine.

When I change it to release mode, the message no longer appear in the following window

[image]

Is there other way I can use, so that I can display message in releae mode for metro app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine when I try it in a sample C++ store app, built from the "Blank App" project template.  Simply added a button and implemented its Click event handler:

```
void App1::MainPage::Button_Click_1(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"Test\n");
}
```

And tested both the Debug and Release builds.  Your screenshot shows the wrong selection, you want "Debug".  The only other possible glitch is that you are running the Release build without the debugger attached.

Comment: My project is in C#, with a DLL in C++. Yup, I just realize the release build debugger type is set to Managed only. Changing it to "Managed and Native" solved the problem.

Comment: The debugger type can be changed to "Mixed (Managed and Native)" from your app's project properties -> "Debug" -> "Debugger type" -> "Application Process".

Answer (score 0):

you can roll your own debug printer with

Platform::Details::Console::WriteLine

in c++/cx

Comment: It is C++ metro and there is no MFC. Hence, I cannot use TRACE.

Comment: But, which window does the output go? I look through window under VIEW menu, but find none of them getting printed.